# Why is this promise returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

I am trying to write a simple function like this

```
const joinLeague = async () => {
    const league = await attemptToJoinLeaugeIfItExists({ id, leaguePin })
    console.log(league, 'fl')

    if (league) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

and I have made a firebase helper like this

```
export const attemptToJoinLeaugeIfItExists = ({ id, leaguePin }: any) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        res(
            firebaseApp
                .database()
                .ref(`users/${id}`)
                .once('value')
                .then((snapshot) => { `
                    firebaseApp
                        .database()
                        .ref(`leagues`)
                        .once('value')
                        .then((snapshot) => {
                            console.log('in here')
                        })
                }),
        )
    })
}
```

however, `league` is logging out as undefined and `in here` is logging out second. however, I thought it would be the other way around? I thought it would "await" for this function to resolve then once it's resolved, it would show me the result. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you already try to use the `then()` function at your attemptTo.. call?

Comment: You are using the [explicit promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). You don't need it, you just need to do `return firebaseApp.database().ref(/* ... */).once(/* ... */).then(/* ... */)`

Comment: Also, the nesting of another call to `firebaseApp` inside the `.then()` is likely incorrect. I suspect there is a better way to structure this but I am not familiar with firebase and also I'm not even sure why you need that.

Comment: You should probably use the standard naming convention of `resolve/reject` rather than `res/rej`.

Comment: @jarmod I thought `res`/`rej` are pretty standard.

Comment: Your helper is resolving immediately. But the code inside your resolve it not.

Comment: @VLAZ Interesting, I've never seen them used. Maybe I should get out more ;-)

Comment: @Bibberty `res` receives a promise, so the whole of the result will wait for that promise to resolve first. Promises automatically flatten/merge if the result is another promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
export const attemptToJoinLeaugeIfItExists = ({ id, leaguePin }: any) => {
    return firebaseApp
                .database()
                .ref(`users/${id}`)
                .once('value')
                .then((snapshot) => { `
                    return firebaseApp
                        .database()
                        .ref(`leagues`)
                        .once('value')
                })
}
```

you're currently immediately resolving your outer promise but with an inner promise, and that inner promise doesn't return anything at all, hence undefined. Just return the promise directly. Cleaner, simpler.

Comment: ahhh! I knew it was something simple. I ended up immediately realising this and then resolving the inner part but I think yours is cleaner so will refactor to that, thanks!